# Cron stopped logging to /var/log/cron.log

Tags: cron, logs, rsyslog

A month ago I set cron to log to `/var/log/cron.log` by modifying `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. Logging worked great until I changed permissions on `/var/log` (by easing permission restrictions), and forced logrotate to rotate the logs by executing `logrotate --force /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. Since then, cron seems to have stopped logging. There is no longer a `/var/log/cron.log`. I executed `sudo touch /var/log/cron.log` to create it, but it has remained 0 bytes since.

More details on what I did with the permissions:

I ran `sudo chmod 775 /var/log`, and subsequently changed permissions back with `sudo chmod 755 /var/log`. All other services appear to be logging correctly, and cron jobs are actually running (verified with `ps aux | grep rsync`, since I only run rsync via cron).

I wasn't sure of the correct user and group access rights for `cron.log` so I tried changing it to `syslog:adm` like most of the other log files, but that didn't help, so I switched it back to `root:root`,

Current permissions on cron.log: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root      root       0 Apr 27 16:34 cron.log`

Not sure where to go from here. I know I can have cron log to any file I'd like (either by adding `>> /path/to/logfile` to end of cron job entries or by editing `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`), but for consistency, I would prefer it continue logging to cron.log. I suppose I could add `>> /var/log/cron.log` to the end of each cron entry, but that seems a little hacky to me.

EDIT: As per my comment below, I changed the log location to `/tmp/cron.log`and logging has resumed. At first, I had assumed this implied that either the folder or file permissions are wrong. However, I checked them against another machine running the same distro, and the folder permissions were correct. The file permissions were not restrictive enough, the correct permissions can be set with `sudo chmod 640 cron.log`.

As a test, I deleted the empty cron.log, and it was never recreated. I modified the rsyslogd config to have it log to crond.log, but the file was never created.

Comment: I just had the same problem, I uncommented the line in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf to enable logging into cron.log but the file wasn't created :( I then manually created it with a touch and it was always empty.  
  
I finally succeeded to make working by typing :  

sudo chmod 640 /var/log/cron.log && sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/cron.log

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't try to edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` ?!
As you know you can force rsyslog to log service that hasn't specific logger.
So I suggest read `man rsyslog.conf` to know how make service making log and edit the service to send logs here ( edit somewhere like `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` to configure log section ).

Comment: I would like it to continue logging to `/var/log/cron.log`, though. However, you gave me an idea: for troubleshooting purposes, I'm going to change the destination in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` to something like `/tmp/cron.log`. If it begins logging again, that should indicates a permissions issue with either `/var/log/` or the log file itself.

Comment: That's a good idea. I by myself for service I wrote use this function for logging. Hope it helps you ;)