# cron is no longer logging, but it seems to be running

Tags: cron, logs

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 as a server on a remote machine.
I have confirmed that cron is running as a service:

```
$ sudo service cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-02 12:17:55 PDT; 4h 45min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 2769 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 526)
     Memory: 4.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─2769 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

And it has jobs to run under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` :

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/tmp/test.sh' >>/tmp/crontest 2>&1
```

which creates correct output:

```
$ cat /tmp/crontest 
Mon 02 May 2022 05:02:01 PM PDT
Mon 02 May 2022 05:03:01 PM PDT
Mon 02 May 2022 05:04:01 PM PDT
```

But is not being logged:

```
$ cat /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf 
cron.*              /var/log/cron.log
```

```
$ ls -lt /var/log/cron.log
-rw-rw---- 1 syslog adm 0 Mar 28  2021 /var/log/cron.log
```

I have stopped and restarted the service. I have rebooted the server. I changed the group permissions. I tried to change the log directory to `/tmp` per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279769/47735), which did not work, so I am not thinking this is a permissions issue.

I am not sure how to go forward from here. There are lots of people with similar issues, but mostly these seem to be related to misconfigured crontabs. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**:
Adding the journalctl output. Seems to be working there too.

```
$ journalctl -xe -u cron.service | tail

May 02 12:17:55 sidero systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit cron.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit cron.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 736.
```

Comment: What does the systemd-journal tell you? 'journalctl -xe -u cron.service'

Comment: Added above. Seems to be working.